# Python Submodule Import Discrepancy

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.6, python-import

I am dynamically importing the numpy package into a python environment of another proprietary system. The top level `numpy` package gets imported from the right place, but the `numpy.random` package is pointing to the standard library. Why is this happening?

### Code

```
import sys

LIB_PATH = 'T:\\Some\\Path\\'

if LIB_PATH not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, LIB_PATH)

import numpy

print numpy
print numpy.random
```

### Output

```
<module 'numpy' from 'T:\Some\Path\numpy\__init__.pyc'>
<module 'random' from 'C:\Python26x64\Lib\random.pyc'>
```

Why is `numpy.random` pointing to `C:\Python26x64\Lib\random.pyc`. When I run this from my standard python interpreter at `C:\Python26x64\`, then random is indeed the one in the numpy package

Comment: This is very odd because `numpy.random` is not even defined in a `random.py` file. `numpy.random` should point to an `__init__.py` file in and directory named `random`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked for me. It don't think its a good solution cause it requires changing one line of code in the `numpy` package. Nonetheless, it allow us to use `pandas` and `numpy` from an embedded Python interpreter in a proprietary software by simply adding a folder to the `sys.path`.

**File Changed**

`T:\Some\Path\numpy\__init__.py`

**Line Before**

*Line: 171* - `import random`

This line assumes that the `random` will be loaded from `T:\Some\Path\numpy\random\`

**Line After**

*Line: 171* - `from numpy import random`

This forces it to use the `random` package from `numpy` instead of the standard package

I thought I'd just leave there here and one of the un-accepted answer until someone can come up with a better solution.